# Downloading videos from multiple web pages

Tags: google-chrome, automation, file-download, screen-scraping

I'm trying to download videos from a list of web pages.

There is 1 video per page. The page is rendered using JavaScript, and is totally blank with JS disabled.

I've tried [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html) but I believe this doesn't work because it doesn't parse JS.

The individual videos can be downloaded using [Video DownloadHelper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-downloadhelper/lmjnegcaeklhafolokijcfjliaokphfk), however I have several hundred pages to process, so I'd like to automate this.

I'm looking at [Kantu browser automation](https://ui.vision/kantu), however I'm unsure if I can use that to identify the video file and download it.

Looking at the page source and network inspector in Chrome, it's not a simple html5 video, but a sequence of split mp4 files, each accessed using a key value pair in it's url for authorisation.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how to approach this?

Comment: Are all the web pages from the same website and all have the same format? Can you give a link to an example page?

Comment: They are all from the same website, but I'm not able to share it publicly as the urls are secret. They're part of a paywalled education site that the company I'm working at has. The company wants to download the original video files from the platform.

Here's a publicly available link on the same platform though, it should be the method: https://view.knowledgevision.com/presentation/ad49e40a7bc642fe9ffab4edef63416a

Comment: If the URLs only differ in a range of numbers, you could use [DownThemAll](https://www.downthemall.org/) with its feature of [Batch downloads](https://www.downthemall.org/howto/help/english-menu/batch-downloadsbatch-descriptors/).

Comment: Thank you but it looks like DownThemAll is not being updated and has been removed from Firefox Addons

Comment: Are the URLs in a numerical sequence?

Comment: No but I have a CSV file with them in.